# Turning a range of numbers into a cell to be referred to in the MOD function

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

So in a mod formula I have:

```
=IF(MOD(A2,A5)=0,"X",0)
```

I only want to allow the values between 8 - 15 to be entered in Cell A5

Thanks a lot in advance for your help.

Comment: how do you expect to divide by a range, i.e you can't divide 10 by 8to15. Or do you want to set set cell A5 to only allow for value between 8 and 15 ?

Comment: "Or do you want to set set cell A5 to only allow for value between 8 and 15 ?"

Yes.

I want the mod formula to return an X every time the value in A2 (an amount of work hours) enters that interval (8 to 15). Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply data validation to cell A5,
Select the cell, then on ribbon, go to Data -> Data Validation -> Data validation.

[image]

The enter the requirements of what can be entered into that Cell, see below for reference.

[image]

Comment: Would this solution also take into account numbers that are above 16? For example, my machine amounted to 8 x 8 = 64 hours and I need the formula to tell me again that I need to perform a special service on it. I want the formula to notify me each time the amount of work hours enters that numerical range (8 to 15 hours of use).

Answer (score 1):

Select A5- go to **Data**- **Data Validation**- Select **Custom** and enter the formula:

```
=AND(A5>=8,A5<=15)
```

[image]

Comment: What this does is restrict the information that can be entered into that cell. What I want is a formula to count each time the number in A2 is a multiple of the numbers between 8 and 15. So if the amount of work hours in A2 is 64, 65, 66 or 150, 149, 147 or 8000, 8001 the formula should behave in the same way.

Comment: @MichałM you didn't mention any of that in your question, Lee has simply answered what you asked

Comment: @PeterH True, my bad. Now that I have specified that, is it possible to get further help?